# Node typescript library environment specific configuration

Tags: node.js, typescript, shared-libraries

I am new to node and typescript. I am working on developing a node library that reaches out to another rest API to get and post data. This library is consumed by a/any UI application to send and receive data from the API service. Now my question is, how do I maintain environment specific configuration within the library? Like for ex:

Consumer calls `GET /user`
user end point on the consumer side calls a method in the library to `get data`

But if the consumer is calling the user end point in test environment I want the library to hit the following API Url

for test `http://api.test.userinformation.company.com/user`
for beta `http://api.beta.userinformation.company.com/user`

As far as I understand the library is just a reference and is running within the consumer application. Library can for sure get the environment from the consumer, but I do not want the consumer having to specify the full URL that needs to be hit, since that would be the responsibility of the library to figure out.

Note: URL is not the only problem, I can solve that with environment switch within the library, I have some client secrets based on environments which I can neither store in the code nor checkin to source control.

### Additional Information

(as per jfriend00's request in comments)

My library has a LibExecutionEngine class and one method in it, which is the entry point of the library:

```
export class LibExecutionEngine implements ExecutionEngine {
    constructor(private environment: Environments, private trailLoader: 
    TrailLoader) {}

        async GetUserInfo(
            userId: string,
            userGroupVersion: string
            ): Promise<UserInfo> {
               return this.userLoader.loadUserInfo(userId, userGroupVersion)
        }
}

export interface ExecutionEngine {
    GetUserInfo(userId: string, userGroupVersion: string): Promise<UserInfo>
```

}

The consumer starts to use the library by creating an instance of the LibraryExecution then calling the getuserinfo for example. As you see the constructor for the class accepts an environment. Once I have the environment in the library, I need to somehow load the values for keys `API Url`, `APIClientId` and `APIClientSecret` from within the constructor. I know of two ways to do this:

### Option 1

I could do something like `this._configLoader.SetConfigVariables(environment)` where `configLoader.ts` is a class that loads the specific configuration values from files(`{environment}.json`), but this would mean I maintain the above mentioned `URL` variables and the respective `clientid`, `clientsecret` to be able to hit the URL in a json file, which I should not be checking in to source control.

### Option 2

I could use `dotenv` npm package, and create one .env file where I define the three keys, and then the values are stored in the deployment configuration which works perfectly for an independently deployable application, but this is a library and doesn't run by itself in any environment.

### Option 3

Accept a configuration object from the consumer, which means that the consumer of the library provides the URL, clientId, and clientSecret based on the environment for the library to access, but why should the responsibility of maintaining the necessary variables for library be put on the consumer?

Please suggest on how best to implement this.

Comment: The library needs to be told what it's environment configuration is by the host application either through environment variables, via a known location config file or via initialization parameters passed to the library.  There might be something it can figure out itself, but others it has to be told by the calling code.  If you showed very specific code and a specific configuration item you were trying to figure out, we could offer info on whether you can figure that out or not.

Comment: @jfriend00: I added additional information.

Comment: Where do the `URL, clientId, and clientSecret` come from?  Are they different for each developer using your library?   Or are they the same for every instance of the library?  If they are different, how are they obtained?  If they are the same for every instance, then you basically have to distribute them when you distribute your library, right?

Comment: They do not change per consumer/developer. but they do change per environment. I am not quite sure what you mean by distribute, do you mean publish?

Comment: So, each developer using your library gets their own `URL, clientId, and clientSecret` from you?  If so, I'd say you package these values into a file and they give you a path to that file when they create an instance of your library.  You can have a recommended place that they put the file if you want, but they need to tell you where it is or need to put it in a default place that you look.  You can't "figure out" what these values are.  They're analogous to license keys.

Comment: How does the developer get these items from you in the first place?  Are you sending them an email containing them.  Sending them a file containing them?  Customer downloading them.  Customer getting them in a web page after some purchase or registration?  Using some installer that carries out a transaction with your web site to get them?  This problem can only be solved well with an understanding the whole flow of information.  It can't be solved with just the pieces of information you've put in your question so far.

Comment: So, I think I got some clarity. Lets call my Library `L`, and consuming app `C1` and the API that the library makes a call out to get user info as `A`. All are internal applications in our org and have a OAuth setup to be able to communicate, our infosec team provides those clientids and secrets to individual applications, so I think my clarity here is: `C1` would request their own `clientid` and `clientsecret` to hit `A`'s `URL`, `C1` would then pass in the three config values to the library, which the library uses to communicate with `A`. Same applies for some `C2` in the future.

Comment: Which would mean that `L` somehow needs to accept a full configuration object with all required config values from its consumers `C1`, `C2` etc. Thanks for your discussion, really helped me visualize this.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the proper approach.  The library is just some code doing what it's told.  It's the client in this case that had to fetch the clientid and clientsecret from the infosec team and maintain them and keep them safe and the client also has the URL that goes with them.  So, the client passes all this into your library, ideally just once per instance and you then keep it in your instance data for the duration of that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I think I got some clarity. Lets call my Library `L`, and consuming app `C1` and the API that the library makes a call out to get user info as `A`. All are internal applications in our org and have a OAuth setup to be able to communicate, our infosec team provides those clientids and secrets to individual applications, so I think my clarity here is: `C1` would request their own `clientid` and `clientsecret` to hit `A`'s `URL`, `C1` would then pass in the three config values to the library, which the library uses to communicate with `A`. Same applies for some `C2` in the future.
>
> Which would mean that `L` somehow needs to accept a full configuration object with all required config values from its consumers `C1`, `C2` etc.

Yes, that sounds like the proper approach. The library is just some code doing what it's told. It's the client in this case that had to fetch the clientid and clientsecret from the infosec team and maintain them and keep them safe and the client also has the URL that goes with them. So, the client passes all this into your library, ideally just once per instance and you then keep it in your instance data for the duration of that instance